# My LED lights flicker when i use my TV remote, why does that happen?

Tags: television

My tv remote is not connected to my LED lights, and whenever I use my remote for the tv my lights flicker a bunch of different colors when impress a button on the remote. Please help, I'm very confused and want answers, thank you.

Comment: What make and model are your LED light fixtures/bulbs?

Comment: I actually don't know, but it says for the model "SSL0100-M-5V((IC) "     and the lights are from Amazon

Comment: There are 'smart' bulbs that you can run (turn on/off, dim, change colors, etc.) with an application on your phone.   Do you have those?  Maybe they are conflicting with the remote.

Comment: I will take a SWAG: Both the LEDs and TV are controlled by IR or RF. Some TV remotes have both. Put the remote in your pocket or something that will block the IR and see if that solves your problem. If it does you LEDs are IR controlled, if not Both the LEDS and TV remote have RF. The best solution is to change whichever is cheaper, as the interference will not go away. If we had make (the model number comes up blank) and a link to technical information on each device that would help us help you.

Comment: Amazon is flooded with cheap Cheese crud from 3rd party vendors ("Ships from: Amazon / Sold by: some random name here")  This stuff is the equivalent of eBay.  It ships via Prime because Amazon also lets third party sellers use their warehousing and shipping facilities (buy stuff on eBay it often shows up in a gray/blue Amazon truck).  So for Prime members they let 3rd party items also ship with Prime. **Expect all such items to be dangerous garbage**.  Here, you're running into the "garbage" aspect.